# Save & Cancel buttons has disappeared from SharePoint list Form

Tags: sharepoint-online, list-form

I created a SharePoint List and a Power App off the list.

Not everyone in the Company has Power Apps, so the idea was to edit the list from the App and directly in the list by pressing New button which opens a form. At first the Form had a Save button at the bottom. But now this has disappeared. There is a save and cancel button a the top of the form, but when trying to save from there a popup appears "Skip to main Content", when pressed nothing happens.

I have also moved the columns around and renamed them in SharePoint, then updated the app also. Could this have caused the problem?.

I have other lists in the same workspace and this hasn't caused any problems there.

thanking you in advance

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Please go to the PowerApps to check the OnSubmit and OnCanael function of the app as shown below:

[image]

If it does not work, you could refer to below article to add new Save and Cancel buttom to submit the form:

https://www.c5insight.com/Resources/Blog/tabid/148/entryid/885/powerapps-how-to-customize-save-and-cancel-buttons.aspx